# Не запускается проект CMake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, wxwidgets, visual-studio-2019

Установил wxWidget, решил запустить пример в CMake. Всё настроил, всё подключил. Сборка проекта проходит нормально, но при запуске выдаёт ошибку "Не удалось найти часть пути: C:....\dataview.exe".

Почему он ищет .exe на винде, когда сборка идёт на удалёнку (vb с ubuntu)?

В VS проектах CMake можно оконные приложения делать с использование wxWidgets?

[100%] Built target dataview - Сборка всех файлов завершена.

Comment: не знаю, как там в VS2019, но в VS2015 надо вместо "local debugger" нажимать "remote debugger"

Comment: @Pavel Gridin , в параметрах проекта задана удалённая машина(ip, user, pass), он подключается и закидывает файлы на удалёнку, но .exe ищет на локалке. Сама сборка:

[rsync] rsync -t --delete --delete-excluded -v -r --exclude=.vs --exclude=.git --exclude=out  "." rsync://user@localhost:50330/temp
[rsync] sending incremental file list
[rsync] 
[rsync] sent 318 bytes  received 13 bytes  220.67 bytes/sec
[rsync] total size is 60,609  speedup is 183.11
Завершено копирование файлов (затраченное время: 00h:00m:11s:535ms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно назначил элемент запуска.